# Проверка тригера объектов Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как можно осуществить проверку на тригер обьекта без использования `OnTriggerStay2D` и подобных

Ключевая проблема заключается в том что в этом скрипте, в методе `update` выполняется остановка времени, следовательно другие методы в данном скрипте выполняться не будут, поэтому использовать вышесказанный метод не получится

```
void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))`
        {

            if (paused == false)
            {
                paused = true;
                Time.timeScale = 0;
       }

        }
    }

         void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other)
        {

            if (other.tag == "Player")
            {
                Time.timeScale = 1;

            }

        }
```

как можно реализовать включение времени при столкновении с объектом (скрипт выполняется на объекте с которым сталкиваются)??

Comment: `как можно реализовать включение времени при столкновении с объектом` OnTriggerEnter2D

Comment: @Methorn в этом то и вся проблема, при выключенном времени не работает ничего кроме update, OnTriggerEnter2D тоже

Answer (score 0):

Самый просто вариант - использовать raycast, он работает и при выключенном времени

[Общий гайд, ru](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jNvmp4SZj9c)

[Гайд для 2D, en](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3dDkXQBkwm8)